# Definir o valor da variável como uma equação

Tags: constantes, equações

Eu queria que aparecesse uma equação em função de x e não o valor da equação, é possível? não achei nada, e estou começando agora a programar em javascript e não sei muita coisa

Comment: Seria isto (exemplo basico) `var x = "1+2*3"; console.log(x); console.log(eval(x));`?

Comment: Boa tarde, a resposta resolveu o seu problema?

Answer (score 1):

Se entendi bem, você quer salvar uma equação matemática e executa-la apenas quando for interessante?

Um exemplo simples seria usar `eval();`:

```
var x = "1 + 2 * 3";
var y = eval(x);

console.log(x, "=", y); // Exibe no console 1 + 2 * 3 = 9
```

Claro que muitos vão falar, *eval is bad* e realmente pode-se passar qualquer coisa no eval, o que pode ser um problema, neste caso você pode usar bibliotecas para isto:

- http://mathjs.org - exemplo:

  ```
  math.eval('sqrt(3^2 + 4^2)');           // 5
  math.eval('sqrt(-4)');                  // 2i
  math.eval('2 inch to cm');              // 5.08 cm
  math.eval('cos(45 deg)');               // 0.7071067811865476
  ```
- https://github.com/silentmatt/js-expression-eval/tree/master - exemplo:

  ```
  Parser.parse("2 * x + 1");
  ```

  Comandos:

  - `sen(x)` - seno de x (x está em radianos)
  - `cos(x)` - co-seno de x (x está em radianos)
  - `tan(x)` - Tangente de x (x é ... bem, você sabe)
  - `asin(x)` - arco de seno de x (em radianos)
  - `acos(x)` - arco de co-seno de x (em radianos)
  - `atan(x)` - Arco tangente de x (em radianos)
  - `sinh(x)` - Seno hiperbólico de x (x está em radianos)
  - `cosh(x)` - co-seno hiperbólico de x (x está em radianos)
  - `tanh(x)` - tangente hiperbólica de x (x é ... bem, você sabe)
  - `asinh(x)` - hiperbólica arco-seno de x (em radianos)
  - `acosh(x)` - hiperbólica arco co-seno de x (em radianos)
  - `atanh(x)` - hiperbólica arco tangente de x (em radianos)
  - `sqrt(x)` - Raiz quadrada de x. O resultado é NaN (Not a Number) se x é negativo.
  - `log(x)` - Logaritmo natural de x (não basear-10).
  - `abs(x)` - Valor absoluto (magnatude) de x
  - `ceil(x)` - Tecto de x - o menor inteiro que é> = x.
  - `floor(x)` - Pavimento de x - o maior inteiro que é <= x.
  - `round(x)` - X é arredondado para o número inteiro mais próximo, usando o "gradeschool rounding".
  - `trunc(x)` - parte integrante de um X, parece - `andar(x)` -a menos para número negativo.
  - `exp(x)` - ex (função exponencial / antilogarithm com base e) funções pré-definidas